# Passing a character array as an argument into a thread C

Tags: c, multithreading

Here is a simple snippet of my code

```
int main(void)
{
  pthread_t p1;
  char strr[16];
  memset(strr, '\0', 16);
  sprintf(strr, "Data: %s", data);
  pthread_create(&p1, NULL, thread_function, (void*)strr)
}

void thread_function(void *strr)
{
  //use strr by casting it (char*) strr
}
```

The problem with this code, is that strr is sometimes blank within the thread. Do I have to malloc memory for this? All examples I'm seeing online say this should work.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's NOT guaranteed to always work. You need to make sure the strr variable outlives the thread, which means you need to pthread_join after you pthread_create.

Comment: The problem with the posted code is the moment `main()` exits (there is nothing that stops it from doing so) that `strr` no longer exists, and the thread is left with a *dangling pointer*.  Join the thread before `main()` exits.

Comment: @WhozCraig So, will the main thread stop and wait at Join until the thread is finished executing?

Comment: Not unless you put the `pthread_join` in the main thread. As soon as `main` exits `strr` is no more, any usage, by address or otherwise, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: in general, those parameters passed to a thread should be in `file global` space rather than local variables in the stack

Comment: In the thread suggest a statement similar to: `char *myStr = (char*)strr;`  Then use `myStr` everywhere in the thread

Comment: necessary call in `main()` would be: ` void *retval;  pthread_join( p1, &retval);`   Note: NULL can be used inplace of `retVal` in the call to `pthread_join()` then the variable `void *retval;` is not needed

Comment: the thread should exit with something similar to: `int status  = 0; pthread_exit( &status );`  If the main() function is not going to use the returned value, then this can be simplified to: `pthread_exit( NULL );`